# Get timezone offset in django/python

Tags: python, django

How to get timezone offset in winter/summer time?

For example, if time zone is America/Monterrey, I want to get numbers -6 and -5 for winter/summer, respectively.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

./manage.py shell

```
import django.utils.timezone as tz
import datetime

my_tz = tz.get_default_timezone() # The one in settings.TIME_ZONE

# My dates:
date1 = tz.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(), my_tz)
date2 = tz.make_aware(datetime.datetime(2015,5,1), my_tz)

# Get timezone names
date1.tzname() # CST
date2.tzname() # CDT

# Get offset from UTC
date1.utcoffset() # datetime.timedelta(-1, 64800) is UTC-6
date2.utcoffset() # datetime.timedelta(-1, 68400) is UTC-5

# Get daylight saving time
date1.dst() # datetime.timedelta(0)
date2.dst() # datetime.timedelta(0, 3600) is +1 hour
```

Remember that Django recommeds to install pytz if you are going to use timezones in your app.